# keras custom layer variables doesnt have ndim and shape attributes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a custom layer in keras which has two trainable variables. I am passing this two variables to another function inside which they need to get the ndims and shape of the variables. But it is showing error.  My custom layer code is-

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    assert len(input_shape) >= 3
    input_dim = input_shape[1:]
    print(input_shape)


    self.kernel1 = self.add_weight(
                               shape=self.output_dim[0],input_dim[0]),
                               name = 'kernel1',
                               initializer='uniform',
                               trainable=True)
    print(self.kernel1)

    self.kernel2 = self.add_weight(
                              shape=(self.output_dim[1],input_dim[1]),
                              name = 'kernel2',
                              initializer='uniform',
                              trainable=True)
    print(self.kernel2)


    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at 
    the end

def call(self, x):
     print(x.shape)

     mat1 =np.array(self.kernel1)

     print(K.shape(mat1))
     #print(mat1.ndim)

     mat2 =np.array(self.kernel2)

     print(K.shape(mat2))
     #print(mat2.ndim)



     output1 = Myoperation(x,mat1,1)
     output = Myoperation(output1,mat2,2)

     return output


def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

inside the function Myoperation, it needs to calculate 
`m2=list(np.shape(M))[1]`  ; M is mat1 or mat2enter code here
The error is -

> IndexError: list index out of range
>   if we use mat1.shape to check the shape, we get
>   TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got

please help

Comment: You cannot mix numpy arrays with tensors from Keras. You should probably find another way to do what you need to do inside `MyOperation`. If you want the shapes as tuples you should use `K.int_shape(tensor)`.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks sir. It works fine now .